# Why when adding a hash to a hash, Ruby seems to nest the added hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a two-dimensional hash like the following:

```
permissions['enrollment'] = ['read' => true, 'create' => true, 'update' => true]
permissions['invoices'] = ['read' => true, 'create' => false, 'update' => false]
```

This is what I do...

```
permissions = Hash.new
permissions['enrollment'] = ['read' => true, 'create' => true, 'update' => true]
permissions['invoices'] = ['read' => true, 'create' => false, 'update' => false]
```

When I "puts" permissions in irb I get this...

```
{
   "enrollment"=>[{"read"=>true, "create"=>false, "edit"=>false}],
   "invoices"=>[{"read"=>true, "create"=>false, "update"=>false}]
 }
```

As you can see from the above output, there seems to be a hash inside another hash for permissions['enrollment'] `[{}]`!!!

I want to access the read permissions for enrollment like this: `permissions['enrollment']['read']` but according to the `puts permission` it won't work and I get this error `TypeError: can't convert String into Integer`

For me to access the read permissions for enrollment I have to do this: `permissions['enrollment'][0]['read']`.

How can I make the enrollment read permissions just like this... `permissions['enrollment']['read']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is off. Hash is delimited by curly braces. Square brackets are for arrays. You might confuse the two if you're coming from PHP world. Try this:

```
permissions = Hash.new
permissions['enrollment'] = {'read' => true, 'create' => true, 'update' => true}
permissions['invoices'] = {'read' => true, 'create' => false, 'update' => false}
```

Comment: Yep, coming from a PHP world. Thanks :)